# How to make different images appear when hovering over corresponding words in list in Javascript and/or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, hover

I have a list of "series", and I want an image connected to said series to pop up when the user hovers over the series name in the list. I also want it to pop up with a `transition` of `.5s`.

I've hit a catch 22, where if I use hover effect in CSS and go from `display: none;`  -> `display: block;` I can't animate, but if I do it from `opacity: 0;` -> `opacity: 1;`, the images must be child elements, and when the user hovers over their absolute location they also appear, whereas I only want them to appear when hovering over the corresponding word.

Every solution I've found has dealt with using one of these two techniques, or is only in reference to a single image appearing when you hover over an entire section, so I'm looking for a solution in Javascript.

```css
li img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    display: none;
}

a.s1:hover img {
    opacity: 1; 
    display: block;
}

a.s2:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="series-1.html" class="s1">Series 1
    <div class="images">
    <div class="image1">
        <img src="image1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
        <img src="image2.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="series-2.html" class="s2">Series 2
    <div class="images">
    <div class="image1">
        <img src="bowl.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
        <img src="octupus.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution can help you:

> Note: When you create animations using CSS, avoid using the "display"
>   property to hide the elements.

---

```
<a href="series-1.html" class="s1">
  <p>Series 1</p>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QYQ0I1mvFDE/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QYQ0I1mvFDE/maxresdefault.jpg">
</a>

<a href="series-2.html" class="s1">
  <p>Series 2</p>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QYQ0I1mvFDE/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QYQ0I1mvFDE/maxresdefault.jpg">
</a>
```

---

```
img {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 10%;
  margin:2px;
}

a.s1 {
  height: 10px; 
  display:block;
}

a.s1:hover {
  height: auto; 
}
a.s1:hover img {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

---

Demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvMxWm